# Hindu Gods associated with ravens

Tags: gods, animals

Many Hindu Gods and Goddesses are often associated with animals : Shiva with the bull, Durga with the lion, Vishnu with the eagle etc.

Which of them is associated with the raven?

Comment: If raven and vulture are the same then Shani Dev is the answer. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17557/4732

Comment: @Rickross If raven and vulture are considered the same, Hari would count. (And obviously Garuḍa and  Aruṇa)

Comment: Crows and Ravens.

Comment: @DoubtfulMonk Hara Kirāta is a hunter, so I guess it is implied he associates with scavenging animals to find kills and weak animals. Not an explicit relation though.